# how to open a new browser page in GWT

Tags: gwt

I want to open new Page in browser  which will be some component .
like I am in  a page "MainPage "its a composite

Now on a click of a button I need to open a new page "DiagramPage" (its a composite)

I dont want to use a full MVP  (as these are the only 2 pages in my app).

Secondly when I am in DiagramPage (with the click on a button in MainPage).

from Diagrampage when I click on Browsers back button , It should take me back to MainPage and with all the things saved, Like whatever checkbox I did check on Mainpage previously and all.

Any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a `PopupPanel`?

Comment: Not allowed by client

Comment: You do know that `PopupPanel` doesn't actually create a popup (new window or tab) but us just a div displayed on top of your page?

Comment: yeah, but if its possible to go to a new page  and then with browser back button we can get back to last page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GWT `History` should be all you need in this case. Read [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsHistory.html) for further information.

It all works with history tokens added to the URL, e.g. http://test.com/#firstPage

To enable the history, include this in your HTML template:

```
<iframe src="javascript:''"
    id="__gwt_historyFrame"
    style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
```

You'll need to listen for history change events like this:

```
History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        String historyToken = event.getValue();
        /* Set your new page content here based on the token */
    }
});
```

Then store the user selections on the new page in some sort of data structure. When the user clicks the back button, you'll get back to the previous "page" where you can just get the information from that data structure.

Comment: thanks , i can store the information of last page in some data structure thing .. But when that Last Page get opened with History change , How will I get that Dat Structure, Can I pass that as argument somewhere

Comment: @junaidp What I do is the following: I have a structure called `ParameterStore` which is `static`. When I have a page that might rely on other information, this page checks the store if the other information is present. If so, it will update its content accordingly, otherwise it will show the default. No need for parameter passing.

Comment: I think if I use eventBus , then I can send the last page information to the new page in the arguments , But not sure how will i do this in History.newItem("")

Comment: @junaidp I thought you didn't want to use MVP?

Comment: thanks , yeah i dont want to use MVP ,thats why not going to eventBus..  Now I have the page DiagramView , which i need to open  on history change .. So what will I exactly do on history.addValueChaneghandler.... the line where u said " /* Set your new page content here based on the token */"

Comment: @junaidp Well, since it's a different "page", I simply clear my container (the `RootPanel` that contains my page content) and add the new stuff.